# Issue with creating rails project using template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create project using template from [here](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/blob/master/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan-template.rb)

but when i'm trying to execute

```
rails new app -m https://raw.github.com/rails3-application-templates/blob/master/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan-template.rb -T
```

it says

```
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I googled about this issue, found few answers on stackoverflow, but nothing helped me. I tried to reinstall rails\ruby, rvm, set default version of ruby and so on. 
Any idea what to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The templates are deprecated and don't seem to work. On the page is a deprecation message for the templates [see here](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates). Try the [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) instead.

Comment: arent deprecated means that they just not supporting\developing anymore?
But thanks for link, ill give it a try

Comment: They didn't work for me too. I've tried it about 4 weeks ago.

Comment: This is not your fault. There are some dependency problems in the templates, which you see in the trace you've posted. Run gem install railties and try the templates again. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: if i remember correctly railties its core rails gem, which already installed